# Legend for Multi-Index Dataframe Plot Does Not Match Plot Colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, multi-index

Here's a sample of the dataframe `new_merged` I'm plotting:

```
cluster    PredictionDate
FGCI 1.5   2022-04-11         0.778682
           2022-04-11         1.686295
           2022-05-10         1.689775
           2022-05-10         0.780289
           2022-06-09         0.781591
           2022-06-09         1.692596
FGCI 2.0   2022-04-11         1.176237
           2022-04-11         2.592334
           2022-04-11         2.071005
           2022-04-11         6.745330
           2022-04-11         1.089879
           2022-05-10         6.746528
           2022-05-10         1.176446
           2022-05-10         2.071373
           2022-05-10         2.592795
           2022-05-10         1.090073
           2022-06-09         2.071265
           2022-06-09         2.592660
           2022-06-09         6.746177
           2022-06-09         1.176384
           2022-06-09         1.090016
Name: weighted_MAPE_contrib, dtype: float64
```

And the code used to generate the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for cluster, date in new_merged.groupby(level = 0):
    ax.bar(date.index.get_level_values('cluster').values,
            date['weighted_MAPE_contrib'], 
             color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
             )
    set_size(10,8)
   
    ax.set_ylabel('UPB-Weighted Mean Absolute Percentage Error')
    ax.set_title('UPB-Weighted MAPE on Cluster Level for Grouped Vintages')
    locs, labels = plt.xticks(); plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)
    

plt.legend(new_merged.index.unique('PredictionDate'))

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

The plot seems to be working mostly, but the legend doesn't match the colors on the chart. I  do want it to be plotting the colors by `PredictionDate` so we can see how much the MAPE for each cluster corresponds with the date, but I'm not sure if it's plotting that incorrectly, or if the legend is incorrect.

If I try this:
`plt.legend(['2022-04-11', '2022-05-10', '2022-06-09'])`
I just get the dates instead of the timestamps in the legend, but why don't the colors of the legend match the colors in the bars? I understand that this formatting of `plt.legend()` simply manually generates the legend, but if I try to put the legend in the for loop, it generates a legend with 25+ labels, so I'm not sure how to tie the legend to the actual plot.

So basically my main objective is to match what the plot show's color-wise with the labels of the legend.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want. You want the X-axis being the dates, and each bar being a cluster (and one color per cluster throughout the dates)? what about the duplicate values for same date-cluster (like FGCI 1.5 -2022-04-11)? do you want to sum them?

Comment: No, I want the X and Y axes to remain the same, but I want the colors of each bar to correspond to the `weighted_MAPE_contrib` for each `PredictionDate` within each cluster. And for duplicate values we could just average out the MAPEs for those dates.

Comment: It's even possible that the chart is already working as I want it to, but I'm not totally sure how to verify that, or confirm if maybe the legend is faulty. Because clearly I have three colors already going on, but I'm not 100% sure what they correspond to. And obviously the legend makes no sense in the context of the plot.

Comment: Try this `new_merged.groupby(level=['cluster','PredictionDate'])['weighted_MAPE_contrib'].mean().unstack('PredictionDate', fill_value=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)` and let me know if it is what you look for

Comment: @Ben.T That's perfect, thank you! Just what I was looking for.